# How to extract value in AWK script when entries are uncertain?

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have some log files like:

```
[INFO] [TYPE] entryA: aaa entryB: bbb entryD: ddd
```

But some entries are not logged in some files. What should I do if I want to extract some values into CSV file, making missing entry value empty or specific value?
For example, an ideal output for above line when extracting A, B, C and D is:

```
aaa,bbb,null,ddd
```

or

```
aaa,bbb,,ddd
```

Comment: Request you to please try to add your efforts in your post which you have tried to solve this, as we all are learn here, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following `awk` and let me know if this helps you. Considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown sample.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  array["A"];
  array["B"];
  array["C"];
  array["D"]
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i=="entryA:" || $i=="entryB:" || $i=="entryC:" || $i=="entryD:"){
       gsub(/entry|:/,"",$i);
       a[$i]=$(i+1)}
   };
  for(j in array){
    val=j in a?(val?val "," a[j]:a[j]):(val?val "," "null":"null")
   };
  print val;
  val=""
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering the point that `entryC` and `entryD` are optional, you could use regex groups:

```
/.*entryA:\s(\w+).*entryB:\s(\w+)(?:\sentryC:\s(\w+).*|\sentryD:\s(\w+).*)/
```

should be replaced with:

```
$1,$2,$3,$4
```

And the result would be:

```
"aaa,bbb,,ddd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

You can make the entries optional by using the `?` quantifier in a regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $line = '[INFO] [TYPE] entryA: aaa entryB: bbb entryD: ddd';

my %entries;
@entries{qw{ A B C D }} = $line =~ /\[INFO\] \[TYPE\](?: entryA: )?(\S*)(?: entryB: )?(\S*)(?: entryC: )?(\S*)(?: entryD: )?(\S*)/;
say join ',', @entries{qw{ A B C D }};
```

But it's easier to extract the entries one by one in a loop:

```
my %entries;
$entries{$1} = $2 while $line =~ /entry([A-D]): (\S+)/g;
say join ',', map $_ // "", @entries{qw{ A B C D }};
```